# Why do PyTk Tkinter control value variables fail to update if stored in a list? What is the alternative?

Tags: python, tkinter

The control variable fails to work if a reference to an object in a list is used as the variable property of a widget. The following code illustrates an example of an application object set to a list of TkInt objects. A test example is just set to a member variable that is a single TkInt object works as expected.
Why does this fail and what is the correct way to manage widgets and control variables that are variable in number?

```
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()
        self.line_whole = [tk.IntVar() for _ in range(6)]

    def createWidgets(self):
        tk
        self.line_whole=list()
        #self.line_whole = [tk.IntVar() for _ in range(6)]
        self.line_whole_cb = list()
        for x in range(6):
            self.line_whole.append(tk.IntVar())
            self.line_whole_cb.append(tk.Checkbutton(self,variable=self.line_whole[x]))
            self.line_whole_cb[x].pack(side="left")
        self.test_val = tk.IntVar()
        self.test_cb = tk.Checkbutton(self,variable=self.test_val)
        self.test_cb.pack(side="bottom")
        self.output_record_btn = tk.Button(self)
        self.output_record_btn["text"] = "Output Check Values"
        self.output_record_btn["command"] = self.say_hi
        self.output_record_btn.pack(side="top")

        self.QUIT = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red",
                                            command=root.destroy)
        self.QUIT.pack(side="bottom")

    def say_hi(self):
        print("checks:",",".join([str(tk_int.get()) for tk_int in self.line_whole]))
        print ("test_check",self.test_val.get())

root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I was using this reference linked from the standard python documentation for viersion 3.5 which said to use tk.IntVar http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/control-variables.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a corrected version with minimal changes:

You were calling `createWidgets` before `self.line_whole` was set. I'm assuming that's why you had recreated it. You simply needed to switch the order you were calling things. Minor thing, if you don't plan on changing the `onvalue` and `offvalue` attributes why not use a `BooleanVar()`? Since the only values this can take are 0 and 1 and these are the defaults of the checkbuttons off and on values. Either one works of course and the choice is merely semantics.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.line_whole = [tk.IntVar() for _ in range(6)]
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        #self.line_whole = [tk.IntVar() for _ in range(6)]
        self.line_whole_cb = list()
        for x in range(6):
            self.line_whole_cb.append(tk.Checkbutton(self, 
                variable=self.line_whole[x]))
            self.line_whole_cb[x].pack(side="left")
        self.test_val = tk.IntVar()
        self.test_cb = tk.Checkbutton(self,variable=self.test_val)
        self.test_cb.pack(side="bottom")
        self.output_record_btn = tk.Button(self)
        self.output_record_btn["text"] = "Output Check Values"
        self.output_record_btn["command"] = self.say_hi
        self.output_record_btn.pack(side="top")

        self.QUIT = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red",
                                            command=root.destroy)
        self.QUIT.pack(side="bottom")

    def say_hi(self):
        print("checks:",",".join([str(tk_int.get()) for tk_int in self.line_whole]))
        print ("test_check",self.test_val.get())

root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
root.mainloop()
```